# How to remove text shadow on JSX tags

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to remove this shadow:

[image]

So that it looks like a regular HTML:

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: 1) Any way to get a short code example that shows the issue? I'm not JS person myself but can check a few places to find what style does it. 2) You can also try this.. but I'm not sure if this will work here: select some code (e.g. a whole tag) in such a file, invoke `Help | Find Action...`, locate there "Jump to Colors and Fonts" and invoke it -- see if popup will have that listed. P.S. It's not text shadow but a background color. Normally (in HTML/XML file) that would be `Tag` style.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, you are right! It's `Tag's` background color in `Editor -> Color Scheme -> XML`. For some reason it seems the studio treats JSX as XML instead of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally (in HTML/XML file) that would be `Tag` style. And XML styles may be taking over HTML here (as an underlying language in IDE's styling hierarchy perhaps).

I'm not sure if this will work here but try this anyway (can be used in other scenarios):

- Select some code (e.g. a whole tag) in such a file.
- Invoke `Help | Find Action...` (or Search Everywhere and focus on "Actions" tab)
- Locate `Jump to Colors and Fonts` entry there and invoke it.
- See if a popup will have the related style listed *(does not seem to list it here in PhpStorm using HTML+PHP file in my quick test -- only lists PHP styles)*.

**P.S.** It's not a "text shadow" but a background color.